# Unable to call safeTransferFrom method from a JS api file

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have deployed my ERC721 contract on polygon testnet from owner(ox43b....81). I have created a small node server to interact with my contract through web3. I m using truffle config

```
//truffle-config.js
polygon-testnet: {
  provider: new HDWalletProvider(privateKey, https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com),
  network_id: 80001,
  gas: 6000000,
  gasPrice: 10000000000,
  confirmations: 2, 
  timeoutBlocks: 200,
  skipDryRun: true
}
//index.js file
function test(){
const owner = await myContract.methods.owner().call()
console.log('contract owner', owner) //ox43b....81

//miniting token
 const mint = await myContract.methods
      .safeMint(owner,1001, 'google.com')
      .send({ from: owner, gas: 100000 }) // is this the write way of calling ??

//token transfer
const transfer = await myContract.methods
      .safeTransferFrom(acc1, acc2, 1003)
      .send({ from: acc1, gas: 1000000 }) // is this the write way of calling ??
}
```

bcz i m getting err in both function calling: Error: Returned error: unknown account.

> NOTE: I am not calling my contract func from truffle console. I m calling through a JS api file index.js

I know there is another way by using web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction() to mint & transfer the token.

Q.1 Is signing is reqd? Can't we access the contract method directly as i did above ?

Q.2 By using web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction() method i can able to mint the tokens successfully but i am facing issue in token transfer (using safeTransferFrom()). There are two cases:

```
case 1: i am transferring the token which is created/minted by contract owner(ox43b....81) to any other individual user address.

    const fromAddress = 'ox43b....81' //owner of the contract
    const toAddress = '0x26....7D'
    const tokenId = 10001 // created by owner(ox43b....81)
    const tx = {
        from: ownerAddress, // ox43b....81 --> owner who created contract
        to: contractAddress,// 0xfe.....24
        nonce: nonce, // nonce with the no of transactions from our owner address
        gas: 1000000, // fee estimate to complete the transaction
        data: await myContract.methods
          .safeTransferFrom(fromAddress, toAddress, tokenId)
          .encodeABI()
      }
// do signing stuff & send it
```

so in this case i m able to transfer the token successfully.

case 2: i am transferring the token which is created/minted by another(not contract owner) user(0x26....7D) to any other individual user address / or to owner.

```
const fromAddress = '0x26....7D' (not the owner of contract)
const toAnyAddress = '0x5e....5a' // any other user
const tokenId = 10002 // created by user '0x26....7D' (not the owner of contract)
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress, 'latest')
const tx = {
    from: fromAddress, // 0x26....7D -> is this right? or i put contract owner adr? 
    to: contractAddress,// 0xfe.....24
    nonce: nonce,
    gas: 1000000, // fee estimate to complete the transaction
    data: await this.myContract.methods
      .safeTransferFrom(fromAddress, toAnyAddress, tokenId)
      .encodeABI()
  }
// do signing stuff & send it
```

so in this case i m getting err - Fail with error 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'.

I need solution for my case 2. Is there something related with locked/unlocked accounts? How can i fix it?
Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> *Q.1 Is signing is reqd? Can't we access the contract method directly as i did above ?*

The `.send()` method of the web3 `Contract` instance performs/requests the signature in the background. So it's always signed - just not with an explicit "sign" keyword in the code in this case.

> *Q.2 There are two cases:*

This is not related to the way you sign the transaction.

The second case fails because the token holder has not approved the spender (i.e. the transaction sender) to spend their tokens.

You need to invoke the `approve(<spender>, <tokenId>)` function from the token holder address first, to be able to successfully use the `transferFrom()`.

```
// assuming `acc1` is holder of the token ID `1003`
// approve the `owner` to spend the `acc1`'s token
await myContract.methods.approve(owner, 1003).send({from: acc1});

// transfer token `1003` held by `acc1` ... and send the transaction from the `owner` address
await myContract.methods.transferFrom(acc1, recipient, 1003).send({from: owner});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Petr for your response. Have a ques. The `owner` you mean the contract owner ?

Comment: @ChandanKumar Yes, i mean the contract owner.

Comment: and if `acc1` is holder of token id `1003` and i want to send the token id `1003` from `acc1` address then approval is reqd or not ?   `await myContract.methods.transferFrom(acc1, recipientAddress, 1003).send({from:acc1})`

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "send the token from...". The important factor is who is the **transaction** sender. If it's the same as the token holder (in your case `acc1`), then you don't need the approval... If the transaction sender is **not** the token holder, then you do need the approval.

Comment: but i m getting the err while minting token.                                                          `await myContract.methods.safeMint(owner,1001, 'google.com').send({ from: owner, gas: 100000 })` i m writing just these 3 lines of code. no any signing operation.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the `safeMint()` implementation? I suggest you post a separate question with steps to reproduce the issue - it might be complicated to post the whole repro steps in a comment.

Comment: Err is `unknown account` and inside safe mint i have called `_mint(to,tokenid)` function from ERC721.sol of @openzeppelin thats it

Comment: The `unknown account` comes from your node. You're trying to sign the transaction with an address (`acc1`) that neither your local web3 instance or the node doesn't know the private key to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240251/discussion-between-chandan-kumar-and-petr-hejda).